# Mapping Absolute / Relative (Local) Paths to Absolute URLs

Tags: php, url, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I need a fast and reliable way to map an absolute or relative *local* path (say `./images/Mafalda.jpg`) to it's corresponding absolute URL, so far I've managed to come up with this:

```
function Path($path)
{
    if (file_exists($path) === true)
    {
        return rtrim(str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($path)), '/') . (is_dir($path) ? '/' : '');
    }

    return false;
}

function URL($path)
{
    $path = Path($path);

    if ($path !== false)
    {
        return str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], getservbyport($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'], 'tcp') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $path);
    }

    return false;
}

URL('./images/Mafalda.jpg'); // http://domain.com/images/Mafalda.jpg
```

Seems to be working as expected, but since this is a critical feature to my app I want to ask if anyone can spot any problem that I might have missed and optimizations are also welcome since I'm going to use this function several times per each request. Anyone?

Comment: Possibly because they think it should be wiki? (I'm not sure, myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential issue to look out for is symbolic links.  If DOCUMENT_ROOT contains a part that is a symlink, things will blow up (since realpath() will expand that symlink).

Of course, the solution might be as simple as wrapping $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in realpath() as well.

Comment: That would be a problem indeed, better throw a `is_link()` call in there, thanks. Can you think of any optimizations in order to make it faster?

Comment: Not sure.  I'm fairly sure the filesystem-related stuff is going to be the slowest bit.  But you need it. The str_replaces should be fast.

Comment: Also: not sure is_link() is the way to go.  You'd have to test each part of the path.  Probably more sane to just let realpath() do it.  As long as you're always dealing with real paths, you know symlinks won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I always absolute paths, but I also start any custom PHP project with a bootstrap file where I define the most commonly used paths as constants, based on values extracted from `$_SERVER`.

This is how I define my root paths :

```
define("LOCAL_PATH_ROOT", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
define("HTTP_PATH_ROOT", isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] : (isset($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) ? $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] : '_UNKNOWN_'));
```

The path `LOCAL_PATH_ROOT` is the document root. The path `HTTP_PATH_ROOT` is the equivalent when accessing the same path via HTTP.

At that point, converting any local path to an HTTP path can be done with the following code :

```
str_replace(LOCAL_PATH_ROOT, RELATIVE_PATH_ROOT, $my_path)
```

If you want to ensure compatibility with Windows based servers, you'll need to replace the directory seperator with a URL seperator as well :

```
str_replace(LOCAL_PATH_ROOT, RELATIVE_PATH_ROOT, str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', $my_path))
```

Here's the full bootstrap code that I'm using for the [PHP PowerTools boilerplate](https://github.com/PHPPowertools/Boilerplate) :

```
defined('LOCAL_PATH_BOOTSTRAP') || define("LOCAL_PATH_BOOTSTRAP", __DIR__);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE SEPERATOR ALIASES
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("URL_SEPARATOR", '/');
define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("PS", PATH_SEPARATOR);
define("US", URL_SEPARATOR);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE ROOT PATHS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ROOT", '');
define("LOCAL_PATH_ROOT", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
define("HTTP_PATH_ROOT",
        isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) ?
        $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] : (
        isset($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) ?
        $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] : '_UNKNOWN_'));

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE RELATIVE PATHS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("RELATIVE_PATH_BASE",
        str_replace(LOCAL_PATH_ROOT, RELATIVE_PATH_ROOT, getcwd()));
define("RELATIVE_PATH_APP", dirname(RELATIVE_PATH_BASE));
define("RELATIVE_PATH_LIBRARY", RELATIVE_PATH_APP . DS . 'vendor');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_HELPERS", RELATIVE_PATH_BASE);
define("RELATIVE_PATH_TEMPLATE", RELATIVE_PATH_BASE . DS . 'templates');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_CONFIG", RELATIVE_PATH_BASE . DS . 'config');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_PAGES", RELATIVE_PATH_BASE . DS . 'pages');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET", RELATIVE_PATH_BASE . DS . 'assets');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_IMG", RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET . DS . 'img');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_CSS", RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET . DS . 'css');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_JS", RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET . DS . 'js');

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE LOCAL PATHS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("LOCAL_PATH_BASE", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_BASE);
define("LOCAL_PATH_APP", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_APP);
define("LOCAL_PATH_LIBRARY", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_LIBRARY);
define("LOCAL_PATH_HELPERS", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_HELPERS);
define("LOCAL_PATH_TEMPLATE", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_TEMPLATE);
define("LOCAL_PATH_CONFIG", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_CONFIG);
define("LOCAL_PATH_PAGES", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_PAGES);
define("LOCAL_PATH_ASSET", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET);
define("LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_IMG", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_IMG);
define("LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_CSS", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_CSS);
define("LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_JS", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_JS);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE URL PATHS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
if (US === DS) { // needed for compatibility with windows
    define("HTTP_PATH_BASE", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_BASE);
    define("HTTP_PATH_APP", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_APP);
    define("HTTP_PATH_LIBRARY", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_HELPERS", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_TEMPLATE", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_CONFIG", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_PAGES", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET);
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_IMG", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_IMG);
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_CSS", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_CSS);
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_JS", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_JS);
} else {
    define("HTTP_PATH_BASE", HTTP_PATH_ROOT .
            str_replace(DS, US, RELATIVE_PATH_BASE));
    define("HTTP_PATH_APP", HTTP_PATH_ROOT .
            str_replace(DS, US, RELATIVE_PATH_APP));
    define("HTTP_PATH_LIBRARY", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_HELPERS", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_TEMPLATE", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_CONFIG", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_PAGES", false);
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET", HTTP_PATH_ROOT .
            str_replace(DS, US, RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET));
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_IMG", HTTP_PATH_ROOT .
            str_replace(DS, US, RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_IMG));
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_CSS", HTTP_PATH_ROOT .
            str_replace(DS, US, RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_CSS));
    define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_JS", HTTP_PATH_ROOT .
            str_replace(DS, US, RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_JS));
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE REQUEST PARAMETERS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("REQUEST_QUERY",
        isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) && $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] != '' ?
        $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] : false);
define("REQUEST_METHOD",
        isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) ?
        strtoupper($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) : false);
define("REQUEST_STATUS",
        isset($_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]) ?
        $_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"] : false);
define("REQUEST_PROTOCOL",
        isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]) ?
        substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"], 0,
        strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"], '://') + 3) : 'http://');
define("REQUEST_PATH",
        isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) ?
        str_replace(RELATIVE_PATH_BASE, '',
        $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) : '_UNKNOWN_');
define("REQUEST_PATH_STRIP_QUERY",
        REQUEST_QUERY ?
        str_replace('?' . REQUEST_QUERY, '', REQUEST_PATH) : REQUEST_PATH);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE SITE PARAMETERS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("PRODUCTION", false);
define("PAGE_PATH_DEFAULT", US . 'index');
define("PAGE_PATH",
        (REQUEST_PATH_STRIP_QUERY === US) ?
        PAGE_PATH_DEFAULT : REQUEST_PATH_STRIP_QUERY);
```

If you add the above code to your own project, outputting all user constants at this point (which can do with `get_defined_constants(true)` should give a result that looks somewhat like this :

```
array (
  'LOCAL_PATH_BOOTSTRAP' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples',
  'URL_SEPARATOR' => '/',
  'DS' => '/',
  'PS' => ':',
  'US' => '/',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_ROOT' => '',
  'LOCAL_PATH_ROOT' => '/var/www',
  'HTTP_PATH_ROOT' => 'localhost:8888',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_BASE' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_APP' => '/libraries/backend/Data',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_LIBRARY' => '/libraries/backend/Data/vendor',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_HELPERS' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_TEMPLATE' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/templates',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_CONFIG' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/config',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_PAGES' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/pages',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_IMG' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/img',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_CSS' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/css',
  'RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_JS' => '/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/js',
  'LOCAL_PATH_BASE' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples',
  'LOCAL_PATH_APP' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data',
  'LOCAL_PATH_LIBRARY' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/vendor',
  'LOCAL_PATH_HELPERS' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples',
  'LOCAL_PATH_TEMPLATE' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/templates',
  'LOCAL_PATH_CONFIG' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/config',
  'LOCAL_PATH_PAGES' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/pages',
  'LOCAL_PATH_ASSET' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets',
  'LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_IMG' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/img',
  'LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_CSS' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/css',
  'LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_JS' => '/var/www/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/js',
  'HTTP_PATH_BASE' => 'localhost:8888/libraries/backend/Data/examples',
  'HTTP_PATH_APP' => 'localhost:8888/libraries/backend/Data',
  'HTTP_PATH_LIBRARY' => false,
  'HTTP_PATH_HELPERS' => false,
  'HTTP_PATH_TEMPLATE' => false,
  'HTTP_PATH_CONFIG' => false,
  'HTTP_PATH_PAGES' => false,
  'HTTP_PATH_ASSET' => 'localhost:8888/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets',
  'HTTP_PATH_ASSET_IMG' => 'localhost:8888/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/img',
  'HTTP_PATH_ASSET_CSS' => 'localhost:8888/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/css',
  'HTTP_PATH_ASSET_JS' => 'localhost:8888/libraries/backend/Data/examples/assets/js',
  'REQUEST_QUERY' => false,
  'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
  'REQUEST_STATUS' => false,
  'REQUEST_PROTOCOL' => 'http://',
  'REQUEST_PATH' => '/',
  'REQUEST_PATH_STRIP_QUERY' => '/',
  'PRODUCTION' => false,
  'PAGE_PATH_DEFAULT' => '/index',
  'PAGE_PATH' => '/index',
)
```