# Storing the HTML output from a local PHP file into a string using file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

There is a header.php file and it contains some php codes that return HTML.
I know I can use require, include to echo the results, but what I want to do is to store its processed output string into a variable.

In a page, I used:

```
$headerHTML=file_get_contents('header.php');
```

Then I got the PHP code output rather than the processed HTML output.
I know adding http:// would help.
But I prefer to keep using relative path, how can I tell the function to treat the php file correctly?

Note: I would like to continue to use this statement `file_get_contents` rather than using `ob_start()` if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd rather use `require()` wrapped inside `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`. I am sure there  is nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: It seems this may be the best way.

Comment: Unless you need to do it in a part of code already wrapped in `ob_`

Comment: `ob_` calls can be nested; in which case the _current_ buffer contents are returned.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `eval()` - it's evil!

Use the relative local path an [automatically map it to a absolute URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752250/mapping-absolute-relative-local-paths-to-absolute-urls).

Answer (score 1):

If URL wrappers are enabled and you want the output of header.php (and you don't want to keep session state) you could use `$headerHTML=file_get_contents('http://yourdomain.tld/path/to/header.php');`, though why you would want to do such a thing eludes me. Are you sure you're not trying to do something that could easily be solved by using templates and caching?

Answer (score 0):

You can check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#56641, hope it helps.